# I can't color my OpenGL circle properly

Tags: opengl, g++, glfw, glew

I am supposed to draw 6 different 2D shapes (dot, line, triangle, square, star, circle) and assign them each a different color. I managed to draw all of them and color them, except for my circle. The color i gave (g_colors_circle) the circle however is drawn from the center of the circle but does not reach the edges. Here is the current output:

[image: output]

Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Here is my code:

`SimpleTriangle.cpp`:

```
#include <cstdio>       // for C++ i/o
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    // to avoid having to use std::

#define GLEW_STATIC     // include GLEW as a static library
#include <GLEW/glew.h>  // include GLEW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h> // include GLFW (which includes the OpenGL header)
#include <glm/glm.hpp>  // include GLM (ideally should only use the GLM headers that are actually used)
using namespace glm;    // to avoid having to use glm::

#include "shader.h"

/*-------------------- Circle Code --------------------*/

//Constants for Circle
#define PI 3.14159265
#define MAX_SLICES 32
#define MIN_SLICES 8
#define MAX_VERTICES (MAX_SLICES+2)*3   // a triangle fan should have a minimum of 3 vertices
#define CIRCLE_RADIUS 0.5

GLuint g_VBO_circle[2];             // identifiers
GLuint g_VAO_circle = 0;

//Vertices for the circle
GLfloat g_vertices_circle[MAX_VERTICES] = {
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
};

GLfloat g_colors_circle[] = {
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};

GLuint g_slices = MIN_SLICES;   // number of circle slices

//raz: i think this generates the vertice values for array of the circle
void generate_circle()
{
    float angle = PI * 2 / static_cast<float>(g_slices);    // used to generate x and y coordinates
    float scale_factor = static_cast<float>(768) / 1024;    // scale to make it a circle instead of an elipse
    int index = 0;  // vertex index

    g_vertices_circle[3] = CIRCLE_RADIUS * scale_factor;    // set x coordinate of vertex 1

                                                    // generate vertex coordinates for triangle fan
    for (int i = 2; i < g_slices + 2; i++)
    {
        // multiply by 3 because a vertex has x, y, z coordinates
        index = i * 3;

        g_vertices_circle[index] = CIRCLE_RADIUS * cos(angle) * scale_factor;
        g_vertices_circle[index + 1] = CIRCLE_RADIUS * sin(angle);
        g_vertices_circle[index + 2] = 0.0f;

        // update to next angle
        angle += PI * 2 / static_cast<float>(g_slices);
    }
}

static void init_circle()
{
    // generate vertices of triangle fan
    generate_circle();

    // create VBO (vertice positions) and buffer the data
    glGenBuffers(2, g_VBO_circle);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO_circle[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 3 * (g_slices + 2), g_vertices_circle, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    // create VBO (vertice color) and buffer the data
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO_circle[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 3 * (g_slices + 2), g_colors_circle, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // create VAO and specify VBO data
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &g_VAO_circle);
    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO_circle);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO_circle[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);  // specify the form of the data 
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO_circle[1]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);  // specify the form of the data

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);   // enable vertex attributes
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------*/

// global variables
GLuint g_VBO[2];            // vertex buffer object identifier
GLuint g_VAO = 0;           // vertex array object identifier
GLuint g_shaderProgramID = 0;       // shader program identifier

static void init()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);   // set clear background colour

    // create and compile our GLSL program from the shader files
    g_shaderProgramID = loadShaders("SimpleVS.vert", "SimpleFS.frag");

    // enable point size
    glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
    // set line width
    glLineWidth(5.0);

    GLfloat verticesPosition[] = {

        //Dot
        -0.7f, 0.7f, 0.0f,
        //Line
        -0.5f, 0.7f, 0.0f,
        -0.2f, 0.7f, 0.0f,
        //Triangle  
        0.2f, 0.75f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f,
        0.4f, 0.4f, 0.0f,
        //Star 
        0.0f, 0.2f, 0.0f,
        0.1f, 0.1f, 0.0f,
        0.2f, 0.05f, 0.0f,
        0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.2f, -0.1f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.2f, -0.1f, 0.0f,
        -0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.2f, 0.05f, 0.0f,
        -0.1f, 0.1f, 0.0f,
        //Rectangle
        -0.8f, 0.4f, 0.0f,
        -0.8f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.3f, 0.4f, 0.0f,
        -0.3f, 0.0f, 0.0f

    };

    GLfloat verticesColor[] = {
        //Dot
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        //Line
        0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        //Triangle
        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        //Star
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        //Rectangle
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    // create VBO and buffer the data
    glGenBuffers(2, g_VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[0]);        // bind the VBO
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verticesPosition), verticesPosition, GL_STATIC_DRAW);      // copy data to buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[1]);        // bind the VBO
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(verticesColor), verticesColor, GL_STATIC_DRAW);        // copy data to buffer

    // create VAO and specify VBO data
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &g_VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[0]);        // bind the VBO
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);      // specify the form of the data
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO[1]);        // bind the VBO
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);      // specify the form of the data

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);   // enable vertex attributes
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
}

// function used to render the scene
static void render_scene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   // clear colour buffer

    glUseProgram(g_shaderProgramID);    // use the shaders associated with the shader program

    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO);           // make VAO active

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);          //Draw dot 
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 1, 2);           //Draw line
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, 3);       //Draw triangle
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 6, 10);      //Draw star
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 16, 4); //Draw rectangle

    glFlush();  // flush the pipeline

    //To draw circle
    glBindVertexArray(g_VAO_circle);            // make VAO for circle active
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, g_slices + 2); // display the vertices based on the primitive type

    glFlush();  // flush the pipeline
}

// key press or release callback function
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    // quit if the ESCAPE key was press
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS) 
    {
        // set flag to close the window
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
        return;
    }
    else if (key == GLFW_KEY_W && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        // renderer using wireframe
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
        return;
    }
    else if (key == GLFW_KEY_S && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        // renderer using wireframe
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        return;
    }
    else if (key == GLFW_KEY_UP && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        if (g_slices < MAX_SLICES)
        {
            g_slices++; // increment number of slices

                        // generate vertices of triangle fan
            generate_circle();

            // bind and copy data to GPU
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO_circle[0]);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 3 * (g_slices + 2), g_vertices_circle, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        }
        return;
    }
    else if (key == GLFW_KEY_DOWN && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        if (g_slices > MIN_SLICES)
        {
            g_slices--; // decrement number of slices

                        // generate vertices of triangle fan
            generate_circle();

            // bind and copy data to GPU
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, g_VBO_circle[0]);
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * 3 * (g_slices + 2), g_vertices_circle, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
            return;
        }
    }
}

// error callback function
static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    cerr << description << endl;    // output error description
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window = NULL;  // pointer to a GLFW window handle

    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);   // set error callback function

    // initialise GLFW
    if(!glfwInit()) 
    {
        // if failed to initialise GLFW
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // minimum OpenGL version 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    // create a window and its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Assignment 1", NULL, NULL);

    // if failed to create window
    if(window == NULL)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window); // set window context as the current context
    glfwSwapInterval(1);            // swap buffer interval

    // initialise GLEW
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) 
    {
        // if failed to initialise GLEW
        cerr << "GLEW initialisation failed" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // set key callback function
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    // initialise rendering states
    init();
    init_circle();

    // the rendering loop
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))       
    {
        render_scene();             // render the scene

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);    // swap buffers
        glfwPollEvents();           // poll for events
    }

    // clean up
    glDeleteProgram(g_shaderProgramID);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, g_VBO);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &g_VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, g_VBO_circle);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &g_VAO_circle);

    // close the window and terminate GLFW
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

`SimpleVS.vert`:

```
#version 330 core

// input data (different for all executions of this shader)
layout(location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 aColor;

// output data (will be interpolated for each fragment)
out vec3 vColor;        //raz: this output is passed as input to the fragment shader

void main()
{
    // set point size
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;

    // set vertex position
    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);

    // the color of each vertex will be interpolated
    // to produce the color of each fragment
    vColor = aColor;
}
```

`SimpleFS.frag`:

```
#version 330 core

// interpolated values from the vertex shaders
in vec3 vColor;

// output data
out vec3 fColor;

void main()
{
    // set output color
    fColor = vColor;
}
```

Comment: Please post all the relevant code **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each vertex in your circle geometry, you must set a color attribute. The 2 array buffers `g_vertices_circle` and `g_colors_circle`, which you are using for your attribute buffers, must have the same number of elements.
If the circle has to be unicolor, you must always use the same color for each element in the color attribute buffer.

In between the primitives the attributes are interpolate according to its barycentric coordinates. You did set the color for the center of the circle and the first outer point, but not the colors for the other outer points and left them undefined (probably black), this causes the effect you can see in your example.

Create a buffer for the color attributes in the same length as your vertex buffer and fill it up when you generate your vertices.
Your revised code should look something like this:

```
GLfloat g_colors_circle[MAX_VERTICES] = {
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};

for (int i = 2; i < g_slices + 2; i++)
{
    // multiply by 3 because a vertex has x, y, z coordinates
    index = i * 3;

    g_vertices_circle[index] = CIRCLE_RADIUS * cos(angle) * scale_factor;
    g_vertices_circle[index + 1] = CIRCLE_RADIUS * sin(angle);
    g_vertices_circle[index + 2] = 0.0f;

    g_colors_circle[index] = 1.0f;
    g_colors_circle[index + 1] = 1.0f;
    g_colors_circle[index + 2] = 0.0f;

    // update to next angle
    angle += PI * 2 / static_cast<float>(g_slices);
}
```

Note, if you only want to have single-color geometry, you can omit the color attributes and set the color through a single uniform variable.

Comment: thank you soo much. it worked! By the way, would you recommend to have just one array of VBOs for all the vertice & color data? Because I used 2 arrays. One for the circle and one for the rest of the 5 shapes. I think my code might be extremely messy